# svn video tutorial

Tags: version-control

I wish to learn/understand/use a version control. Do you know any good video tutorial? I'm programming in PHP and C/C++(learning stage) but i think this is not important as long you get the concept.

How can I get the concept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest reading the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) and playing with a sample repository.  You won't be able to learn nearly as much watching a video as you'd be able to by just playing around with svn.  That being said, [link text](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUXGKxFSxHQ) appears decent (only a quick glance).

Answer (score 4):

Dimecasts has some (5) [video tutorials on using SVN](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/SVN)

- [Creating and Applying patches with Subversion (SVN)](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/52)
- [Learning how to resolve conflicts within Subversion (SVN) using TortoiseSVN](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/34)
- [Setting up a Project in Subversion (Svn)](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/29)
- [Learning the Check-in Dance](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/18)
- [Setting up a Project for Source Control](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/16)

Answer (score 3):

You can find a lot of [Subversion **tutorials on YouTube**](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=subversion+tutorial&search_type=&aq=0&oq=subversion+tutorial).

Also [**BestTechVideos** is plenty of SVN stuff](http://www.bestechvideos.com/search?query=subversion+svn).

Comment: 404. That’s an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a glance at slideshare : http://www.slideshare.net/search/slideshow?q=svn&submit=post&searchfrom=header

You'll certainly find out a presentation that suits your need.

Answer (score 1):

This video is the first one I found that is like what I would do if I sat with you to show you how to use Subversion. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvtdL2fQFts

Comment: +1, there has to be a ton of SVN videos on youtube

Comment: There are several, and the first few I looked at had just about convinced me to fire up the ol' screen recorder and make something that wasn't rambling, inaudible or fuzzy. Also, while TortiseSVN is wonderful, I think the command line is the place to start learning.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWgTyOOufow) for using subversion on windows with [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/catalog) free hosting. BTW, it has much more than svn hosting.

Answer (score 1):

New Video tutorial is avaliable form PluralSight

Introduction to SVN
Introduction to setting up and using SVN for Windows development.

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=intro-to-svn&highlight=john-sonmez_svn-m1-introduction*3!john-sonmez_svn-m2-setup*1,3!john-sonmez_svn-m3-commands!john-sonmez_svn-m4-branching!john-sonmez_svn-m5-best-practices#svn-m1-introduction

you may check this out too